# how to make a "train effect" with vertex manipulation?

Tags: three.js, translation, vertex

Am trying to do this with three.js

I have this PlaneGeometry(a rectangle) and I want it to move along the vertexes of a CircleGeometry, just like a train on a rail.

any idea how to achive this realy smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take your `THREE.Mesh` and `.add(object)` it to a `new THREE.Object3` at the center of your `THREE.CircleGeometry`, then move your `THREE.Mesh` to the edge of the circle by `.set(x,y,z)` it's position. Note that now your mesh is added to the object3, the positions of your mesh will be relative to the object3. This means that when you rotate the object3, the plane will pivot around it, and eventually rotate around the circle.
The way I described would only work for circles. If you want more complex shapes, I'd use `THREE.Spline`.

Hope this helps.